# Accessibility standards with Spring Cloud Dataflow UI

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, wcag2.0, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

Do we know if the Spring Cloud Dataflow UI supports any accessibility standards?
Ideally WCAG 2.1 standards.

Comment: I saw your similar post on github,https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues/1914. When looking for accessibility for a product, I do a google search for *"accessibility"* and limit the search to just that product's website (using the `site` parameter). If any accessibility work is being done, then some results come back. In this case, I did a google search for `site:dataflow.spring.io accessibility` but I didn't see anything related to accessibility so my guess is "no". However, the readme page for dataflow-ui says it uses Angular, which **does** have accessibility.

Comment: I was hoping to find a working example and then I could look at the generated HTML code to see how accessible it is. I looked at https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow#samples but none of them have working examples.  If you have one, I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the response @slugolicious.

The UI project location is: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui
You can find some base HTML under `ui/src` directory.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/tree/main/ui/src

Also, it uses Angular and NPM and maven plugin to build a runnable JAR.
The compiled source can be found here in the runnable JAR:
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/2.10.2/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.10.2.jar

Comment: Yeah, I saw all that. I don't want to set up an environment just to inspect the output. Was hoping for a working example that I could quickly evaluate for accessibility.

Comment: The compiled JAR in the link above is a working example.